# Imported workflows not visible in Sharepoint 2013 Desinger

Tags: sharepoint-designer, designer-workflow

If I save a SharePoint 2013 workflow as a template, then follow the process to add that workflow to a different site in a different site collection, the "imported" workflow is visible in the browser and works.   BUT when the site is opened in SharePoint Designer 2013 that workflow is not visible - making it impossible to modify.

According to Microsoft documentation this should not be the case.   Is there any available technique to fix this issue?

And to compound problems the "imported" workflow does not work. It throws the following error - Something went wrong. To Try again, reload the page and then start the workflow. No access to ULS log as this is an Office/365 site.  (and the originating site of the workflow is also Office/365.

Answer (score 0):

This issue has been resolved.   The site where the workflow was imported did not have SharePoint 2013 Workflow feature activated.  Once that feature was activated the workflows showed up in designer and worked perfectly.